# Select Statement If Condition is Wrong in Sql

Tags: sql, select, case

I am kind new to Sql. I have two tables, and I need to get the data from the second table if a condition based on a field in the first table is wrong as bellow:

First Table

```
(SELECT branch, division, position_code, emp_code, 
 div_brand, div_brand_targets_t2
 FROM sas_provBrand_targets 
) TRGT
```

Then I need to make the `Select` from the second table based on the value of the `TRGT.div_brand` as follow:

```
IF TRGT.div_brand IN ('Other', 'HPC1', 'HPC2')
THEN 
{
 Brand = null
 Category = null
 Subcategory = null
}
ELSE
{
 (SELECT DISTINCT BRAND, REP_BRAND, category, rep_category, 
  sub_category, SUB_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION 
  FROM masterdata.dbo.inventory_item
  WHERE sub_category = TRGT.div_brand
 ) BRNDNAME 
}
```

At the end I need to get the following data to be displayed in the front end

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRGT.branch BRANCH, TRGT.division DIVISION, TRGT.POSITION_CODE POSITION,
TRGT.emp_code SALESMAN, BRNDNAME.brand  + ' - ' +  BRNDNAME.rep_brand BRAND, BRNDNAME.category + ' - ' + BRNDNAME.rep_category CATEGORY, BRNDNAME.sub_category + ' - ' + BRNDNAME.SUB_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION SUBCATEGORY,  TRGT.div_brand_targets_t2 BRANDT2
```

Tables Structure (Note that they are UN-relational tables  )
sas_provBrand_targets Table

```
yr: numeric(4, 0)
mnth: numeric(2, 0)
branch: char(4)
division: char(4)
position_code: numeric(3, 0)
emp_code: char(5)
div_brand: varchar(25)
div_brand_targets_t2: numeric(15, 2)
```

masterdata.dbo.inventory_item

```
division: char(6)
brand: char(5)
rep_brand: varchar(40)
category: char(6)
rep_category: varchar(40)
sub_category: char(8)
SUB_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION: varchar(20)
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle)

Comment: Please provide structure of two tables. There is no such SQL construct as `IF TRGT.div_brand IN ('Other', 'HPC1', 'HPC2')`. You must select the row, set in a variable and then make check with `IF`.

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov. I now I need to use "Case". But, I am just using the "IF" to explain the logic I need to achieve. I also provided the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly when it comes to SQL think set theory not row by row ops.
The trick to achieving the result set you want is to join everything.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRGT.div_brand IN ('Other', 'HPC1', 'HPC2') THEN NULL ELSE BRNDNAME.BRAND END AS BRAND 
 FROM sas_provBrand_targets TRGT

LEFT/INNER>?? JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT BRAND, REP_BRAND, category, rep_category, 
  sub_category, SUB_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION 
  FROM masterdata.dbo.inventory_item
  WHERE 
 ) BRNDNAME ON sub_category = TRGT.div_brand
```

repeat the case statement for each of the columns and add your required columns/ formatting into the main select